# Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015) - Local Branch - Publish unavailable

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a local git repository connected to a server instance on Codebase.  I used the same repository in Visual Studio 2013 and didn't have an issue with creating local branches that I could then publish to the server instance as I started to commit to that branch.  After resolving the issues, I would create a merge request (more of a practice now, being that it isn't in production yet and I haven't brought another team member on board yet) and then after completing the merge request, I could delete the branch on the server and locally.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** The issue I'm running into now however is that the "Publish" option on the local branch isn't an option.  I'm guessing it is an issue with how I brought my git master down from the server, but I don't know where to look from here.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try doing the git stuff from command line ?